# Looping through a for loop then calling a function JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So i cant get it to optput to postman more then one object. when i console.log it i get all of the objects of the array (battletags that ive taken out and replaced with player)

```js
        router.get('/cod/', (req, res) => {
        const pdata = {}
        console.log(req.params)
        API.login(process.env.EMAIL, process.env.PASSWORD).then((output) => {
       
        // Players array,
        players = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3']
        // map through array and create promise for each player and store it in an array
        promises = players.map(player => API.MWBattleData(player))
        // Pass all promises to Promise.all
        // Result will be an array of individual output of each promise
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(result => {
                // Loop through result, and assign the output to pdata
                result.forEach((output, index) => {
                    // index + 1 because starting index will be zero
                    pdata[`p${index + 1}`] = output
                    res.json(pdata);
                })
            })
         })
         });
```

i am getting error in console
node:19134) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/Users/jaredschau/Desktop/cod-tracker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/Users/jaredschau/Desktop/cod-tracker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/Users/jaredschau/Desktop/cod-tracker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
at /Users/jaredschau/Desktop/cod-tracker/routes/posts.js:29:25
at Array.forEach ()
at /Users/jaredschau/Desktop/cod-tracker/routes/posts.js:26:24
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:19134) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19134) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Can you try updating it to `Promise.allSettled`, I've updated my code

Comment: dope its working thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `API.MWBattleData('Player1')` returns a promise. Then you can achieve this via `Promise.all`, which will resolve all promises sequentially and return you an array of results for all promises

```
// Players array,
players = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3', ...]

// map through array and create promise for each player and store it in an array
promises = players.map(player => API.MWBattleData(player))

// Pass all promises to Promise.allSettled
Promise.allSettled(promises)
  .then(result => { // Result will be an array of individual output of each promise

    // Loop through result, and assign the output to pdata
    result.forEach((output, index) => { 
      // index + 1 because starting index will be zero
      pdata[`p${index + 1}`] = output.value;
    })
  })
```

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: I agree with this suggestion. Depending on the use case `Promise.allSettled()` might be a better option.

Comment: Indeed. @KarlGalvez thanks for pointing out. Depending on the status of the promise the output can be stored. Also not to mention it won't reject everything in case one of them rejects.

Comment: Thank you guies for the help... im still learning its getting hung up in postman and not executing any data

Comment: update i did a res.json(pdata)  but it only gives one user any ideas?

Comment: Could you perhaps add a little more code? What is pdata here?

Comment: yea sorry         // map through array and create promise for each player and store it in an array
        promises = players.map(player => API.MWBattleData(player))
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(result => {
                result.forEach((output, index) => {
              
                    pdata[`p${index + 1}`] = output
                    res.json(pdata);

Comment: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: sorry i set up a const pdata ={}  above this function to save the data

Comment: Could you please `console.log(pdata)` at the very last and see what data does it hold?

Comment: i get all of the players in the array

Comment: Could you add an update to your question, and show a little more code how you've done it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise.all() method to create an iterable promises taht resolves an array of the results the input promises. See docs: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

I deduce that you have an array of users.

```
const players = [player1, player2, player3];
```

To create a promise input out of them you can do it like this by using the array.map method that returns an array.

```
Promise.all(players.map(player => API.MWBattleData(player))).then(values => console.log(values))
```

The returned values is an array of output by the promises created from your players array. I hope it helps. Cheers